# What does Hyperledger composer do .Does that create chaincode for fabric or something else?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have been working on hyperledger fabric for some time. But I don’t understand where hyperledger composer comes in place . I do understand that it helps in visualizing the logic and transaction. But what I don’t get is how do you integrate it with fabric network? what does it create? Is it chaincode if not then what?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Compose runtime is chain code that executes the business network archive artefacts created by the end-user.

Perhaps this will help?

https://blog.selman.org/2017/07/08/getting-started-with-blockchain-development/

Comment: Thank you very much dan the blog was very helpful. If you any more such blogs realted to hyperledger please let me know.

Answer (score 9):

The tech answer is that Hyperledger Composer is an abstraction layer over Hyperledger Fabric.

The practical answer is that it is awesome. Think how Angular and hundreds of other frameworks make web programming easier.

It is a framework where you can write your blockchain in Javascript and specify your data objects in an easy to understand text file. Throw in some querying, ACL stuff and pathways to use some nice opensource tools that let you do things like generate a Web API automatically and play around in a web environment without installing anything.

We are using it for the Integra Ledger Legal blockchain. (www.integraledger.com). I just spent the day working in it.

Comment: Good clarification!
Thank you so much